# Inequality between two sequences preserved in the limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

Let $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be two real sequences that satisfy $a_n\geq b_n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and converge to some $a,b$, respectively.

Is it always true that $a \geq b$?

Comment: Yes. What can you say about the limit of $(a_n-b_n)$?

Comment: Suppose you have $a_n \geqslant b_n$, $a_n \to a$, $b_n \to b$ and $a < b$. Try to find a contradiction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If you assume that $a < b$, you can take $\varepsilon = (b-a)/2$ and use the definition of the limit of a sequence to come up with a contradiction, i.e. find an $n$ such that $a_n < b_n$.