# Let $a \leq x_{n} \leq b$ for all n in N. If $x_{n} \rightarrow x$. Then prove that $a \leq x \leq b$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality, proof-verification

Let $a \leq x_{n} \leq b$ for all n in N. If $x_{n} \rightarrow x$. Then prove that $a \leq x \leq b$

Attempt - If I assume that $x$ is greater than both $a$ and $b$. Then since series is given convergent, so after certain stage its elements will lie between $(x-\epsilon , x + \epsilon )$. If I take epsilon to be such that $\epsilon = (b + x) /2$. Then sequence lies to right of $b$, which is contradiction. Same argument for if I take limit to be to left of a. Is this fine? Thanks

Comment: Yes, your argument is great! :)

Comment: Looks good.  Exactly the right idea.  If you get close to a number to the right of $b$, eventually you must be to the right of $b$.

Comment: @TravisJ Can you show how do i convert this to math language of proofs

Comment: I think you want something like $\epsilon=(x-b)/2$.

Comment: @K.Dutta, I wrote an answer that (verbosely) spelled out how to make this formal.  The take-home is make $\epsilon$ such that when $|x_n - x|<\epsilon$ then you know you are outside of the interval.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, or just $\epsilon = x-b$ is good enough...

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks

Comment: @TravisJ Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. That we want something like $(x-b)/2$, or at least positive and less than $x-b$, is clear from the geometry, to make sure that if we back up by $\epsilon$ from $x$, we are still bigger than $b$.  We also need a separate argument to show that $x$ is not less than $a$.

Comment: You can also use results from [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432319/inequality-between-two-sequences-preserved-in-the-limit) for the sequence $(x_n)$ and two constant sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am showing one side only.

If $x<a$ then taking $\epsilon=a-x>0$

Now since $x_n \to x \exists m\in \mathbb N$ such that $x-\epsilon<x_n<x+\epsilon \forall n\geq m$

Then $x_n<x+\epsilon=x+a-x=a$ i.e $x_n<a$ for some $n$ contradiction as $x_n\geq a\forall n$

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track.  As requested in the comment, the formalism is as follows:

If $x>b$, take $\epsilon=x-b$.  Then if $n>N$ it follows that

$$ |x_{n}-x| < x-b.$$

We know that this should mean that $x_n>b$ (which is a contradiction) so let's re-write the terms to make this appear very explicitly.

$$-(x-b) < x_{n}-x < (x-b)$$

Adding $x$ to all three parts of the inequality gives us:

$$ b < x_{n} < 2x-b$$

but of course, we only need that $b<x_{n}$ to get the contradiction.

Comment: Sorry for not accepting the your answer  Only reason was that other user posted before you .So according to ethics i accepted that ..Your answer is fantastic though

Comment: @K.Dutta, no worries.  But, to be clear, the answer you accept is the one you feel best answers your question.  I'm never offended when people don't select my answer--feel free to select as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

Given $\varepsilon>0$, there is a positive integer $N$ such that
$$
|x-x_n|\le \varepsilon \quad \forall n\ge N.
$$ 
It follows that
$$
x_n-\varepsilon \le x\le x_n+\varepsilon \quad \forall n\ge N
$$
and therefore
$$
a-\varepsilon \le x\le b+\varepsilon.
$$
Letting $\varepsilon$ tend to $0$, we get $a\le x\le b$.